# Jekyll not highlighting with rouge highlighter

Tags: jekyll

My Jekyll blog (Github pages) seems not to highlight the syntax properly, both locally hosted and hosted on Github. My `_config.yml` looks as follows

```
#Others
markdown: kramdown

# Syntax highlighting
highlighter: rouge
kramdown:
    input: GFM 
    syntax_highlighter: rouge
```

And in one post I tried fencing a code block with the python tag like this

````
```python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib2.urlopen( "http://www.google.com" ).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```
````

But this renders the page without highlights [link](http://rainymood.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/04/26/ankiscrape.html). Code is on Github available [here](https://github.com/Rainymood/rainymood.github.io). Jekyll version on my system is `3.1.1`.

Comment: Did you read this article: https://help.github.com/articles/using-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages/

Comment: Yes. Could you be a little more specific? Because as far as I'm aware I installed everything and followed all the instructions.

Comment: I was thinking that you will find on this link something that you did not installed yet, fo example [pygments](http://pygments.org/) - higher for python.

Comment: I installed everything etc I was wondering if you maybe knew what I am/are doing wrong because it is not rendering properly

Answer (score 10):

There is three ways to write code snippets in jekyll :

#### 1 - jekyll highlight

```
{% highlight python %}
import urllib2
[...]
{% endhighlight %}
```

#### 2 - fenced code block

````
```python
import urllib2
[...]
```
~~~python
import urllib2
[...]
~~~
````

#### 3 - markdown four space indentation

```
    import urllib2
    [...]
```

Only first and second can produce code highlight with rouge.
The third, the one that you actually use, only surround your code with  tag, but rouge or any highlighter you set, will not be used by kramdown.

So, you can switch to first or second solution.

Another thing, if you want to "color your code", you need an highlight css. [You can search for pygment style sheets.](https://github.com/search?q=pygments%20style)

Comment: Why do I need an external CSS? I thought that Github-pages 'natively' supports rouge highlighting?

Comment: Yes pygments or rouge highlighter are generating the html part, something like giving some semantic to the code (inspect the generated code you will see all the divs added with specific classes for each type of "token"). But the styling part is still devoted to CSS. A Jekyll fresh install always have an highlight scss file. See here : https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/site_template/_sass/_syntax-highlighting.scss

Comment: option 2 works. just place code between "\```java" and "\```", there is no double quote in fact, and the language code is from https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers